# Apache websites stopped working

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd

I built 6 virtual hosts on a new Centos 6.4 server yesterday and they worked absolutely fine - today I got contacted to say that they are no longer working and, as far as I know, nothing has changed yet I cannot get them to come online.

There are 6 hosts on the server each using their own IP address all on eth0:

```
    <VirtualHost x.x.x.1:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/virtual_host/public_html
    ServerName virtual_host.com

    <Directory "/home/virtual_host/public_html">
        Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
        Order deny,allow
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </Directory>

    ServerAlias www.virtual_host.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost x.x.x.2:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/virtual_host/public_html
    ServerName virtual_host2.com

    <Directory "/home/virtual_host2/public_html">
        Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
        Order deny,allow
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </Directory>

    ServerAlias www.virtual_host2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If I try and connect to or even ping the FQDN from outside the server then it times out - the IP for only one of the sites works and will both ping and load the web content.

The IP which works is the main IP of the server (x.x.x.1) which is set up as a virtual host - if I try x.x.x.2 which is also set up as another virtual host then it won't ping or connect and likewise the domain assigned to x.x.x.1 also does not ping or connect.

I am able to SSL and FTP into the server without any issues - DNS is properly pointing to the correct nameservers and so on. I have disabled iptables completely which hasn't made a difference, restarted networking, restarted apache and even rebooted the server to no avail.

There is nothing in error_log being generated currently though this morning I was getting literally thousands of variants of:

```
child pid 24118 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

After a reboot these stopped but there were 30+ every second for over an hour.

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578

Comment: I did see that but that error is no longer occurring since a reboot yet the sites won't come online so I wasn't sure if that was relevant and as the error is no longer happening I cant follow the guidance to troubleshoot that as I need to wait for it to happen again

Comment: Considering that you can't even ping the IP then you know it's not an Apache problem.  Assuming you have no firewall running that may be blocking it, my hunch is that you added the second IP (.2) manually.  Then you rebooted.  Go configure it again and/or put it in the system config files so it'll be added when it boots.